# NSPersistentStoreCoordinator database storage location applicationSupportFolder issue

Tags: cocoa

Right now my App is placing the database in the ~/Library folder but I would like it to place it in a more organized manner ~/Library/App Name but I can not figure out how to do that with this block of code.

```
(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *) persistentStoreCoordinator {

if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSFileManager *fileManager;
NSString *applicationSupportFolder = nil;
NSString *dataFilePath;
NSURL *url;
NSError *error;

fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
applicationSupportFolder = [self applicationSupportFolder];
if ( ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:applicationSupportFolder isDirectory:NULL] ) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:applicationSupportFolder attributes:nil];
}


dataFilePath = [applicationSupportFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"sample.dat"];


if( NO == [[ NSFileManager defaultManager ] fileExistsAtPath: dataFilePath ] )
{

    [[ NSFileManager defaultManager ] copyPath: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"sample.dat"]
        toPath: dataFilePath handler: NULL ];

}

url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataFilePath];
if( url )
{           
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];


    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error]){

        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
    }    
}
return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

This code works it just places the database in a pretty terrible location IMO. I am new to Obj-C and just inherited this code set from a another developer.

UPDATE:

Adding the final working code below.

```
(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *) persistentStoreCoordinator {

if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSFileManager *fileManager;
NSString *applicationSupportFolder = nil;
NSString *dataFilePath;
NSURL *url;
NSError *error;

fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
applicationSupportFolder = [self applicationSupportFolder];
NSString *aappSupportFolder = [applicationSupportFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"APP"];

if ( ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:aappSupportFolder isDirectory:NULL] ) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:aappSupportFolder attributes:nil];
}

dataFilePath = [aappSupportFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"sample.dat"];


if( NO == [[ NSFileManager defaultManager ] fileExistsAtPath: dataFilePath ] )
{

    [[ NSFileManager defaultManager ] copyPath: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"sample.dat"]
        toPath: dataFilePath handler: NULL ];

}

url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataFilePath];
if( url )
{           
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];


    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error]){

        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
    }    
}
return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is very simple just you have to create folder name APP inside library folder of your machine and then you have to move your app inside the same path . Please try below:-

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *pathString= [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSError *err=nil;
//below is your application previous path which we will move to new path
NSString  *dataFilePath = [pathString stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"sample.dat"];
NSString *applicationSupportFolder = [pathString stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"App"];
//Here we have created directory folder as App inside Library below
if ( ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:applicationSupportFolder isDirectory:NULL] ) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:applicationSupportFolder attributes:nil];
}

   if ([fm moveItemAtPath:dataFilePath toPath:applicationSupportFolder error:&err])
        {
            NSLog(@"success");
        }
 else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",[err localizedDescription]);
        }
```

Comment: Very helpful thanks, I was able to use this almost directly I am going to paste my code here for future reference.